# Self-Referencing ManyToMany Relationship TypeORM

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, typeorm

I have just started using TypeORM and I'm struggling getting the following relationship to work:

User->Friends, whereas a Friend is also a User Object.
My getters, getFriends & getFriendsInverse are working, however; I do now want to distinguish between the two. In other words; when I perform a mysql join I do not want to do a left join on friends and another one on inverseFriends.

The getter getFriends() needs to return all friends, regardless of which "side" the object I'm on.

Does that make sense?

This is my model definition:

```
getFriends() {
    // This method should also return inverseFriends;
    // I do not want to return the concat version; this should
    // happen on the database/orm level
    // So I dont want: this.friends.concat(this.inverseFriends) 
    return this.friends;
}

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.friendsInverse, {
    cascadeInsert: false,
    cascadeUpdate: false,
})
@JoinTable()
friends = [];

@ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.friends, {
    cascadeInsert: true,
    cascadeUpdate: true,
    cascadeRemove: false,
})
friendsInverse = [];
```

I hope someone understands my question :D
Thanks
Matt

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct if it answers your question. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I believe I'm 3 years late, but better late than ever. The most upvoted answer **does not** answer the question, as it only works for tree-like and hierarchical structures, so if you follow that example, this would happen:

```
               Fred
               /  \
          Albert  Laura
          /   \
       John   Foo
```

In this example, `Foo` can't be friends with `Fred`, because he can only have one parent. Friends is not a tree structure, it's like a net. The answer would be the following:

```js
import { Column, Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn } from 'typeorm';

@Entity(UserModel.MODEL_NAME)
export class UserModel {
  static MODEL_NAME = 'users';

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', unique: true, length: 50 })
  username: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => UserModel)
  @JoinTable()
  friends: UserModel[];

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
  password: string;
}
```

This would create a table where relations between people would be saved. Now for the next important stuff. How do you query this and get a user's friends? It's not as easy as it seems, I've played hours with this and haven't been able to do it with TypeORM methods or even query builder. The answer is: Raw Query. This would return an array with the user's friends:

```js
async findFriends(id: Id): Promise<UserModel[]> {
    return await this.userORM.query(
      ` SELECT * 
        FROM users U
        WHERE U.id <> $1
          AND EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM users_friends_users F
            WHERE (F."usersId_1" = $1 AND F."usersId_2" = U.id )
            OR (F."usersId_2" = $1 AND F."usersId_1" = U.id )
            );  `,
      [id],
    );
  }
```

(`users_friends_users` is the autogenerated name that typeORM gives to the table where the relations between users are saved)

Comment: From this answer, isn't it better to manually implement this with an empty table as you would in SQL with a junction table? Or am I missing the benefit of using @ManyToMany?

Comment: @talfreds using that annotation will create the junction table automatically for you. That is the magic of the ORM and its annotations. 

It will also, thanks to all of these annotations, automatically generate the migration files with raw queries, which is kind of crazy. I've tried generating a migration after making relatively big/complex changes to my schemas, and it works like a charm.

Comment: @talfreds also, using these annotations consistently instead of making part automatically and part manually will help the ORM keep track of everything.

Comment: Ah, I meant like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55253563/typeorm-how-to-add-extra-field-to-many-to-many-table but I see your point, using @ManyToMany is better if you don't require an extra field or something

Comment: This works perfectly.  I don't suppose you can also show how you performed an update, since by default we can end up with duplicate rows with usersId_1 and usersId_2 inverted.

Comment: @tarmes I don't really remember, but I think that I basically checked if that friend connection was already in the DB when adding a new friend. This should prevented duplicates. Maybe apart from this, and as a precaution measure, you can have a cron that checks the table and cleans it of duplicates.

Answer (score 26):

You can self-reference your relations. Here is an example of a simple directed graph (aka a node can have a parent and multiple children).

```
@Entity()
export class Service extends BaseEntity {

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  
  @Column()
  @Index({ unique: true })
  title: string;

  @ManyToOne(type => Service, service => service.children)
  parent: Service;

  @OneToMany(type => Service, service => service.parent)
  children: Service[];
}
```

An important note to keep in mind is that these relations are not auto loaded when reading an object from the DB with `find*` functions.

To actually load them, you have to use query builder at the moment and join them. (You can join multiple levels.) An example:

```
let allServices = await this.repository.createQueryBuilder('category')
  .andWhere('category.price IS NULL')
  .innerJoinAndSelect('category.children', 'product')
  .leftJoinAndSelect('product.children', 'addon')
  .getMany();
```

Please note how I used different names to reference them (`category`, `product`, and `addon`).

Comment: hi, i already doing this, but when doing a production release the entity Service cannot identify it self

Comment: i'm not sure if this applies in this case. You are talking about a tree structure, but this would be more like a net. There is no 1 parent, x children.

Comment: Yep, definitely this does not work. See my answer for the specific case of the original question of this post.

Answer (score 3):

2021 here, was searching for the same problem and find a way to solve it without custom raw SQL (providing same model as example for simplicity):

```
import { Column, Entity, JoinTable, ManyToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn, JoinTable } from 'typeorm';

@Entity(UserModel.MODEL_NAME)
export class UserModel {
  static MODEL_NAME = 'users';

  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id?: number;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', unique: true, length: 50 })
  username: string;

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 50, unique: true })
  email: string;

  @ManyToMany(type => UserModel)
  @JoinTable({ joinColumn: { name: 'users_id_1' } })
  friends: UserModel[];

  @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 300 })
  password: string;
}
```

The key moment here is to set `joinColumn` for `JoinTable`.

When you are defining ManyToMany relationship, TypeORM automatically creates n-n table `users_friends_users` with one column named `user_id_1` and another `user_id_2` (they are automatically incremented if foreign key is the same)

So it is enough to choose **any** column from this table as "primary join column" and it works

Answer (score 3):

I'm working on a similar feature and facing the same problem.

Defined the same **@ManyToMany** relation as [@Aleksandr Primak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8713246/aleksandr-primak) , but the relation isn't bi-directionnal.

*Example:*

- Case 1 :
  Auto-generated table `users_friends_users` contains value

[userId_1, userId_2] = 70, 19

When I'm logged with userId=70 and request currentUser, it returns the **`friends[19]`**

- Case 2 :
  Auto-generated table `users_friends_users` contains previously's value reversed

[userId_1, userId_2] = 19, 70

Still logged with userId=70 and request currentUser, it returns an empty list of **`friends[]`**

So I guess the only way is to use **`Raw Query`** as [@Javi Marzán](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8906267/javi-marz%C3%A1n) said