# typeorm - how to add extra field to "many to many" table?

Tags: typeorm

**for example:**

3 tables

```
user
user_business_lines_business_line
business_line
```

those created by `typeorm` with the declaration in `User`

```
@ManyToMany(type => BusinessLine)
@JoinTable()
businessLines: BusinessLine[]
```

then, how to add columns fields like

```
@CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
createdAt: Date

@UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
updatedAt: Date
```

to `user_business_lines_business_line`

Comment: This thread has more useful examples https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1224

Answer (score 33):

It is not possible to add custom column in the auto created many-to-many bridge table. So create another table and give one-to-many and many-to-one relationship between them.

**for example:**

Three tables

User -> Table 1

BusinessLine -> Table 2

**UserBusinessLine** -> Bridge Table between User table and BusinessLine table

```
UserBusinessLine table will contain the foreign key of both parent tables and also we can add custom columns into it.
```

In User Table

```
@OneToMany(() => UserBusinessLine, (userBusinessLine) => userBusinessLine.user)
public userBusinessLines: UserBusinessLine[];
```

In BusinessLine Table

```
@OneToMany(() => UserBusinessLine, (userBusinessLine) => userBusinessLine.businessLine)
public userBusinessLines: UserBusinessLine[];
```

In UserBusinessLine Table

```
@ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.userBusinessLines)
public user: User;

@ManyToOne(() => BusinessLine, (businessLine) => businessLine.userBusinessLines)
public businessLine: BusinessLine;

// Custom Colums
@CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
createdAt: Date;

@UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
updatedAt: Date;
```

So now the custom table has the foreign keys of User table and BusinessLine table. Also the CreateddateColumn and UpdatedDateColumn

Answer (score 16):

You can specify custom-join table for ManyToMany relation

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string

  @ManyToMany(type => BusinessLine, businessLine => businessLine.users)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_business_line',
    joinColumn: {
      name: 'userId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
    inverseJoinColumn: {
      name: 'businessLineId',
      referencedColumnName: 'id',
    },
  })
  businessLines: BusinessLine[]
}

@Entity('user_business_line')
export class UserBusinessLine {
  @CreateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  createdAt: Date

  @UpdateDateColumn({ type: 'timestamp' })
  updatedAt: Date

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  userId: number;

  @Column()
  @IsNotEmpty()
  @PrimaryColumn()
  businessLineId: number;
}

@Entity()
export class BusinessLine {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  name: string

  @ManyToMany(type => User, user => user.businessLines)
  users: User[]
}
```

Comment: but you cannot add columns this way

Answer (score 0):

If it is just for a `createdAt` timestamp for example, you could just add an extra column to your `user_business_lines_business_line` table using migrations like this (I am using Postgres):

```
ALTER TABLE "user_business_lines_business_line" ADD "createdAt" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT LOCALTIMESTAMP
```