# Typeorm ManyToMany on self referencing

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, typeorm

I need to create friends that is many to many relation in self referencing table... I am trying to do something like this

```
  @ManyToMany(() => Account)
  @JoinTable({
    name        : 'friendships',
    joinColumns : [
      { name: 'person_1', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
      { name: 'person_2', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    ],
    inverseJoinColumns: [
      { name: 'person_2', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
      { name: 'person_1', referencedColumnName: 'id' },
    ],
  })
  friends!: AccountEntity[];
```

My problem is that friends list is available only in one direction and that is if person_1 is current account. My friends relations need to be in two way if account is person_1 or person_2. I try something like this example but that is not working properly... Does anyone have some idea how to solve this ?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747765/self-referencing-manytomany-relationship-typeorm

Answer (score 0):

I do not know TypeORM so I will leave the conversion to you. I will just provide a Postgres resolution.  

You are just looking to resolve a M:M relationship, the fact that it is self referencing is irrelevant, the solution is the same. Create a resolution table. The difference being that both FKs in the resolution table reference the same parent table. Beyond that there are a couple items you then need to guard against and/or decide upon: Assume persons A and B then

1. Can a person be a friend of themselves? I.e. is the relationship A:A
   valid?
2. Does the reflective relation indicate the same relationship?  I.e.
   is relationship A:B the same relationship as B:A?

In the following I will assume No to the 1st and Yes to the 2nd. The resolution table (FRIENDS) becomes:

```
create table friends( friends_id integer generated always as identity
                    , friend1    integer not null
                    , friend2    integer not null
                    , since      date
                    --- additional attributes 
                    , constraint friends_pk 
                                 primary key (friends_id)                   
                    , constraint friend1_person_fk
                                 foreign key (friend1)
                                 references persons(person_id) 
                    , constraint friend2_person_fk
                                 foreign key (friend1)
                                 references persons(person_id)                                 
                    , constraint friends_not_self_ck 
                                 check (friend1 != friend2) 
                    );
create unique index already_friends on friends
        ( least(friend1 ,friend2), greatest(friend1,friend2) );
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e4f9d15830d5d2154720c216ebc6b42b). You should be able to translate into TypeORM fairly easily. Like I indicated despite being self referencing it is **exactly the same as any other M:M**. Just a couple additional restrictions.