# Designing a many-to-many entity referencing the same table with TypeORM

Tags: javascript, nestjs, typeorm

Lets say I want to map some sort of relationship between users as a many-to-many table:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  name: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => User)
  @JoinTable({ name: 'relationships' })
  relationships: User[];
}
```

How should I go about defining the `Relationships` entity (supposing I'll want to add custom fields to it down the line?)

```
@Entity('relationships')
export class Relationships {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  field: number;

  // how do I map the user fields back to the `User` table
  user1: User;

  user2: User;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following this [documentation](https://typeorm.io/many-to-many-relations#many-to-many-relations-with-custom-properties): (I added the example with courses)

In the entity relationships:

```js
import { Relationship } from "./relationship"

@Entity()
export class User {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column()
    name: string

    @ManyToMany(() => Relationship, (relationship) => relationship.user)
    @JoinTable({
      name: 'relationships',
      joinColumn: { name: 'userID', referencedColumnName: 'id'},
    })
    users: this[]
}
```

```js
import { User } from "./user"
@Entity('relationships')
export class Relationship { // I kept the class in singular
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  public userID!: number

  @Column()
  field: number;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.relationship)
  public user!: User
}
```

I would try something like this?

Comment: TypeOrm seeps to report a `Duplicate column name 'id'` when going for this schema. However you can't really drop the primary generated column field.

Comment: I found this solution too [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43747765/self-referencing-manytomany-relationship-typeorm#answer-65464953):